# python3 http.client ssl certification error

Tags: python, python-3.x, http.client

using python3 and geting the following error

**ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)**

what am i missing can someone help me with this

```
import http.client
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.python.org")
conn.request("GET", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()
print(r1.status, r1.reason)
```

Comment: I works fine. can you provide more information?

Comment: Try to `pip install requests==2.15.1; pip uninstall -y certifi` in your pc.

Comment: that worked.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appear this type issue because the requests versions is not compatible.
Specified the requests module version to 2.15.1, and remove the certifi:

```
pip install requests==2.15.1
pip uninstall -y certifi
```